# How to get the hour from a specific user in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe

I'm trying to get the most acess hour from 3 specif clients, I have already done this:

```
mostUserDict = dict(df['user_id'].value_counts()) 

mostClientDict = dict(df['client_id'].value_counts()) 
print(mostClientDict)
```

This me return by desc order the user with more acess, like:

`{1480: 96, 1610: 94, 1607: 80, 1375: 74, 1710: 65, 1477: 58, 1691: 58, 1729: 44, 1717: 42,...}`

To get the hours from all users I did:

`clientsHours = df[['client_id', 'hour']].groupby('client_id').agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])`
`print(clientsHours)`

```
client_id      
901          18
1339         19
1372         11
1375         12
1379         20
...         ...
```

Now I need to get the hours from the first 3 users in the first dict (1480, 1610, 1607 in this case). I know that I can use a for loop but have another way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can get the top 3 clients and then aggregate their hours values like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_data_set")

top_3_clients = df["client_id"].value_counts().head(3).index

df = df[df["client_id"].isin(top_3_clients)]

aggregate_hours = df.groupby("clientId").agg({"hours": "sum"})
```

You get all the clients based on their value counts and you keep the top 3. Then you filter your DataFrame with only those 3 and aggregate their `hour` column to sum it.

If you need more than 3, you just change the `head(3)` to the number you need.